# Finding ASP.NET source code

Tags: asp.net

Where can I find source code for e.g. XmlSiteMapProvider and other "built-in" stuff for ASP.NET (3.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). It's free, portable and fast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether ASP.NET is included, but some parts of the .NET framework are linked to Source Server - you can then step into the framework code, almost as if it were your own. Here's an article to get you started:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can never find the source code of inbuilt controls due to the fact that they are compiled into assemblies that are part framework.

Why do you need the source?

Comment: In this particular case to find out how to avoid stack overflow in my custom site map provider. I was hoping that XmlSiteMapProvider could give me some insight, but I realized it is a subclass of StaticSiteMapProvider while I need something which is an immediate subclass of SiteMapProvider and doesn't depend on StaticSiteMapProvdier.